# C#: WebBrowser.Document breaks after document processing thread ends

Tags: c#, multithreading, events, browser

It took me whole weekend to realize, when one document processing thread completes, `WebBrowser.Document` object is broken and unusable.

Code like:

```
if (Browser.Document == null) ...
```

raises an exception.

I have some event based scripts which load document into WebBrowser and perform actions on it. An event is raised when all scripts completed.

Then, depending on my document state - i would run other scripts. But **THERE IS NO DOCUMENT**! Why? What happens with it? Is it destroyed, disposed, overwritten by random data?

There is no code between last event .Invoke and testing the document. One line earlier I have document, and the next line it's gone! What happens?!

`System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId` returns other values for those 2 lines. Is there a workaround for this killer? I found only one way to handle it for now - I can reload document with:

`Browser.Url = Browser.Url.` But this is stupid and redundant.

The whole point was to get the document to be able to perform more operations on it with the WebBrowser.

One more thing - the thread which fires my first action chain is executed as a new task. It runs in a different thread than the rest of the code operating on document. I know it's wrong, but the very first time I did it right. Instead of starting new task I used BeginInvoke to run my scripts asynchronously. But this one hangs the whole app on first other invoke in the code. I'm stuck here. If I call browser code in a wrong way - all multithreaded application works, but I loose my document somewhere. If I call it the proper, thread-safe way - the app just hangs and I can't even debug it. Code dies on invoke which never calls the method it should call. Of course silently.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say much without seeing some of the relevant code. My guess is you are trying to reference the object on a thread other than the one it is created on. My suggestion based on an issue I just had to deal with would be to create a static reference to the browser or document object.

Comment: First - Document is read only - even if I would be able to store it somewhere else, I couldn't assign it back to the browser.
Copying the browser object before returning from thread and restoring it afterwards does nothing too - restored object works, but document is broken as it was before.